# Word VSTO Get the default save location set by Office URI scheme

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I am creating a new Word document from a template using the [Office URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) with the nft command using the 'Optional Command argument 2' to set the default save folder.
Is it possible to retrieve the value of this default save folder from VSTO?

I have searched properties of the FileSaveAsDialog, properties of the ActiveDocument, properties of the Application, the CustomXmlParts in the document, and even investigated some WordBasic.FileNameInfo properties to see if it could be found there, but so far without success.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Options.DefaultFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.options.defaultfilepath) property which returns or sets default folders for items such as documents, templates, and graphics.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but this is the application level setting for saving newly created documents. The Office uri scheme allows you to set the default save path at the document level.
When you File > Save As, the value of this parameter is displayed as the InitialDirectory.
What I want to achieve is to retrieve this value programmatically.